# efficient matrix operations on the JVM for a large quantity of medium sized matrices

Tags: java, matrix, linear-algebra, simd, blas

Is it worth to go native without MKL? I have a matrix of about 450 elements in size and want to perform some multiplications and decompositions to calculate:

- a gaussian process
- correlations

My problem is that I will have several million of these matrices and I wonder which option on the jvm should be considered.

In particular, I would be interested in experiences with:

- https://nd4j.org
- http://ejml.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page
- https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze

to me, it looks like BLAS support and optimally SIMD will be very important for fast operation.
Regarding SIMD support I could not find a lot of information so far.

Comment: Those will be important.  Are those matricies independent?  Can you operate on them in parallel?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend** or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. You could try softwarerecs.stackexchange.com , but you really want to study their policies better before doing so ...

Comment: Indeed they are all independent.

Comment: You can parallelize them using one thread per core without any context switching.  Loading them into a parallelStream and applying lambdas will be elegant and efficient.

Comment: You mean without a BLAS backend i.e. like http://ejml.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page using PLAIN java?

Comment: I didn't say either way.  You can still do what I'm suggesting if you choose to use a Java library with native BLAS backing.

Comment: It's hard to keep the SIMD FPUs saturated in code that loads/stores at every step.  If you can usefully do multiple steps of your computation at once while your data is loaded into registers, instead of first using a canned multiply function and then another canned matrix add function or something, there's definitely room for potential gain with hand-vectorized native code.  But if all of your building blocks have enough computational intensity (like matmul), then just calling BLAS functions should be good, esp. if they're small enough to stay hot in L2 cache.